# Enterprise Library 5 Logging, populate LogEntry with additional context information

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I'm trying to figure out is it possible and how to implement this functionality using Enterprise Library Logging.

In my current code I'm handling exceptions like this:

```
exceptionManager.HandleException(ex, "LogException");
```

What I want is to log this exception, but gather additional context information, for example assembly version, what I need to extend \ implement to log this additional context information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use the `Data` property of the exception to attach your additional context information.  Enterprise Library will then map all of the `Data` elements to Extended Properties.

```
try
{
    DoSomething();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.Data["ExecutingAssembly"] = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;

    bool rethrow = exceptionManager.HandleException(ex, "LogException");

    if (rethrow)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Then make sure the log template has the extended properties set to log:

```
Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}
```

Comment: I don't want to modify all my try-catch blocks.